# Proving that a set infers a norm given certain conditions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\bar{B}$ be a set in a vector space $E$. Then $\bar{B}$ is the closed unitary ball for a norm iff

1. $\mathbb{N} . \bar{B} = E$
2. $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in \bar{B}$ for all $x \, ,y \, \in \bar{B}$  and $\lambda \in [0,1]$
3. $\lambda . \bar{B} \subseteq \bar{B}$ for all $|\lambda|=1$
4. If $\lambda x \in \bar{B}$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1)$ then $x \in \bar{B}$
5. $\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n} \bar{B} =0$

I managed to prove that if $\bar{B}$ is a closed unitary ball for some norm, then all those things are true.

Then by defining $\lVert x \rVert = inf \{\lambda : x\in \lambda \bar{B} \}$ I then proved that $\lVert 0 \rVert = 0$ and that if $\lVert x \rVert = 0$ then $x=0$.

Now Im' trying to prove homogeneity but can't. Here's what I have.

$\lVert \lambda x \rVert = inf \{ \alpha : \lambda x \in \alpha \bar{B}\} \leq |\lambda| \lVert x \rVert$

Now I would need to have the inverse inequality, but can't find a way to get there. I feel like there's probably a straightforward way to do this, but can't find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is a little idiosyncratic.

More precisely, $\|x\| = \inf \{ r \ge 0 | x \in r B \}$.

Suppose $x = 0$, then $x \in rB$ for all $r >0$, hence $\|x\| = 0$.
If $\|x\| = 0$, then there are $r_k \ge 0$ such that $r_k \to 0$ such that
$x \in r_k B$. Since $\cap_k r_k B = \{0\}$ (from 5.), we see $x = 0$.

Suppose $\lambda = 0$, then $0 = \| \lambda x\| = |\lambda| \|x\|$.

Suppose $\lambda \neq 0$, then $x \in \lambda \bar{B}$ **iff** ${1 \over \lambda} x \in \bar{B}$. Also, from 3., we have
$x \in \lambda \bar{B}$ **iff** $x \in |\lambda| \bar{B}$.
Then
$\|\lambda x\| = \inf \{ r \ge 0 | \lambda x \in r B \} =  \inf \{ r \ge 0 |  x \in {r \over \lambda} B \}=  \inf \{ r \ge 0 |  x \in {r \over |\lambda|} B \} =  \inf \{ |\lambda| s \ge 0 |  x \in s B \}  = |\lambda| \|x\| $.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not sure why you can say that $x \in \lambda \mathbb{B}$ iff $\frac{1}{\lambda}x \in \bar{B}$. What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $\lambda \neq 0 $ then $x \in \lambda \bar{B}$ **iff** there is some $y \in \bar{B}$ such that $x=\lambda y$ **iff** there is some $y$ such that  $y = {1 \over \lambda } x \in \bar{B}$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I should have written everything out and see that. Thanks a lot for your help.